# Crear una función para que un último elemento sea el primero en C

Tags: lista, imprimir

estoy en una lista doblemente enlazada, tengo las funciones como agregar elementos al principio, al final y en cualquier lugar de la lista, imprimir la lista de principio a fin y al revés también. Si tengo una lista doblemente enlazada que tiene 3 nodos con los números "5, 10 y 15" al imprimirla normal pues salen como "5, 10 y 15", al revés como "15, 10 y 5" y estoy haciendo una función que al imprimirla de manera normal salga "15, 10 y 5" es decir que imprima primero el que está hasta el final.
Lo que he hecho es declarar un apuntador a nodo que inicializo en el primer elemento de la lista y mediante un while hago que llegue hasta el último elemento llamado "current", después declaro otro apuntador de nodo llamada "temp" inicializado en un nodo antes de current a través de su nodo que va hacía atrás. Después en un ciclo while donde evalúo que mientras en el nodo que está atrás de temp y current sean diferentes de NULL se ejecute y dentro del while hago que current en su next apunte a temp y después ambos se regresan una posición a través del nodo que tienen atrás.

*Header con las operaciones de la lista:*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

Estructura del nodo:

```
typedef struct Nodo {
    int valor;
    struct Nodo *next;
    struct Nodo *prev;
} Nodo;
```

Estructura de la lista:

```
typedef struct Lista {
    struct Nodo *head;
} Lista;
```

Función para crear una lista:

```
Lista crearLista() {
    Lista miLista;
    miLista.head=NULL;
    return miLista;
}
```

Función para imprimir la lista desde el primer elemento hasta el último:

```
void imprimir(Lista miLista) {
    if(miLista.head==NULL) {
        printf("No hay elementos en la lista. \n");
    } else {
        printf("Los elementos son: \n");
        Nodo *temp=miLista.head;
        while(temp!=NULL) {
            printf("%i \t", temp->valor);
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Función para imprimir del último elemento al primero:

```
void imprimirReversa(Lista miLista) {
    if(miLista.head==NULL) {
        printf("La lista está vacía \n");
    } else {
        printf("Los elementos son: \n");
        Nodo *current=miLista.head;
        while(current->next!=NULL) {
            current=current->next;
        }
        while(current!=NULL) {
            printf("%i \t", current->valor);
            current=current->prev;
        }
    }
}
```

Función para agregar un primer elemento a la lista:

```
void primerNodo(Lista *miLista, int x) {
    Nodo *newNodo=(Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    newNodo->valor=x;
    newNodo->next=NULL;
    newNodo->prev=NULL;
    miLista->head=newNodo;
}
```

Función para agregar elementos al final:

```
void agregarFinal(Lista *miLista, int x) {
    if(miLista->head==NULL) {
        primerNodo(miLista, x);
    } else {
        Nodo *current=miLista->head;
        while(current->next!=NULL) {
            current=current->next;
        }
        Nodo *newNodo=(Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
        newNodo->valor=x;
        newNodo->next=NULL;
        newNodo->prev=current;
        current->next=newNodo;
    }
}
```

Función para agregar elementos al principio:

```
void agregarPrincipio(Lista *miLista, int x) {
    if(miLista->head==NULL) {
        primerNodo(miLista, x);
    } else {
        Nodo *newNodo=(Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
        newNodo->valor=x;
        newNodo->next=miLista->head;
        newNodo->prev=NULL;
        miLista->head->prev=newNodo;
        miLista->head=newNodo;
    }
}
```

Función para agregar elementos en cualquier parte de la lista:

```
void agregarNLugar(Lista *miLista, int x, int lugar) {
    Nodo *temp=miLista->head;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<(lugar-1); i++) {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    Nodo *temp2=temp->next;
    Nodo *nuevoNodo=(Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    nuevoNodo->valor=x;
    nuevoNodo->next=temp->next;
    nuevoNodo->prev=temp;
    temp->next=nuevoNodo;
    temp2->prev=nuevoNodo;
}
```

Función para que el último elemento se vuelva el primero pero que no me sale:

```
void direccionNodos(Lista *miLista) {
    Nodo *current=miLista->head;
    while(current->next!=NULL) {
            current=current->next;
    }
    Nodo *temp=current->prev;
    
    while(current->prev!=NULL && temp->prev!=NULL) {
        current->next=temp;
        temp=temp->prev;
        current=current->prev;
    }
}
```

*Implementaciones*

```
#include"TDA.h"

int main() {
    Lista miLista;
    
    agregarPrincipio(&miLista, 10);
    agregarPrincipio(&miLista, 9);
    agregarPrincipio(&miLista, 8);
    
    //primerNodo(&miLista, 10);
    
    agregarFinal(&miLista, 11);
    agregarFinal(&miLista,13);
    
    //agregarNLugar(&miLista, 12, 4);
    
    imprimir(miLista);
    
    printf("\n");
    
    imprimirReversa(miLista);
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    //direccionNodos(&miLista);
    //imprimir(miLista);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quizá sea más fácil si agregaras un puntero al último nodo. Así no tendrías que recorrer la lista completa cada vez que quieras hacer cambios en el final.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿La función no hace lo que debería o el programa se cuelga? No lo veo claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ser una lista doblemente enlazada al invertir el sentido de cada nodo hay que mantener además una copia de cual era el siguiente nodo antes de la inversion para poderse mover a este despues de la inversion de cada nodo. En esta solucion hacemos el recorrido una vez desde el principio y no desde el final como esta en tu propuesta inicial, ya que eso requeriria un doble recorrido de la lista: uno para llegar al final y otro desde el final hasta el principio

```
void direccionNodos(Lista *miLista) {
    if(miLista->head==NULL) return; //Lista vacia, nada que modificar
    if(miLista->head->next==NULL) return; //Lista de un solo elemento; Nada que modificar
    
    Nodo *newHead;
    Nodo *c, *n;
    for(c = miLista->head; c != NULL;)
    {
        //Se requere copia del apuntador al siguiente nodo
        //porque al invertir el sentido del nodo esta referencia se pierde
        n = c->next;
        //Invierte el sentido del nodo
        c->next = c->prev;
        c->prev = n;
        
        //Si el siguiente nodo es nulo llegamos al final y tenemos la nueva cabeza de lista
        if(n==NULL) newHead = c;

        //Pasa al siguiente en el orden antes de la inversion
        c=n;
    }
    
    //Asigna la nueva cabeza de lista
    miLista->head = newHead;
           
}
```